# QuantLib: Bumps to the Yield Curve

Tags: python, quantlib

Does anyone know how to replace a value in a yield curve object for revaluing a bond (to get partial durations)? I suppose you could re-do all of these steps again, but it seems like there's a better way to just adjust it in place?

http://khandrikacm.blogspot.com/2014/03/usd-yield-curve-building-using-python.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the setup is as in the page you linked, then it's as simple as writing (for instance):

```
swaps[(5,Years)].setValue(0.016)
```

setting a new value will cause the curve to be marked as out of date: the next time you ask the bond for its value, the curve will automatically recalculate and the bond will return the updated price.

See also [QuantLib: Building Key Rate Risks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46279785) to see how to bump the curve in a different way.

Comment: Thanks Luigi. In referencing the code above, I'm getting a weird result where 

`bp = .0001
shock_term = (5,Years)

swaps[shock_term].setValue(bbg_value('USSW5 Curncy'))
ref = swaps[shock_term].value()

swaps[shock_term].setValue(bp * 5)
new = swaps[shock_term].value()`

keeps returning a 'new' value that isn't the one that corresponds to new setValue() change. Said another way, no matter what I put in the `swaps[shock_term].setValue()` it seems to be stuck on a value from a prior test. Do I need to reset something? I tried using `ref` like in your YouTube tutorial.

Comment: Apologies how ugly the format is for that question - I could repost as another question if that's easiest.